# javascript reflection library

Tags: javascript, jquery, reflection

Is there any library for reflection in javascript?

I need to list all global variables, functions or list all variables of an object. I'm dealing with a tool which allows javascript and html, but there is no any debugger there.

Thanks

Comment: Reflection isn't needed. Every variable and property is public.

Comment: Ok, how to list all global variables and functions?

Comment: They are properties in the `window` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably easier than you're expecting.  Take a look at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24549/How-to-Inspect-a-JavaScript-Object which shows the `for(member in object) { }` syntax

Comment: It works for an object but how to list all global variables and functions?

Comment: "global" variables are really just members of the `window` object